# Check if date column is complete and sequential and calc rolling means

Tags: r, date, datetime

**Part 1:**
I have a dataframe with 600,000 observations of with a date time column. I want to know if that data time column is in sequential order and if there are missing days. So does the order go 12-01-01, 12-01-02, 12-01-03 and are there missing days.

**Part 2:**
Ultimately I would like to calculate 4 day, 7 day, and 14 day rolling averages for wind speed. I want to make sure the days are consecutive so there are not large gaps between days when a rolling average is calculated. The data also comes from multiple buoy locations so I will want to have the rolling averages grouped by lat and lon. I mainly need help how to address calulating the rolling averages and accounting for gaps in the date column

Data

```
grid_data <- structure(list(time = structure(c(757386000, 757389600, 757396800, 
757400400, 757404000, 757407600, 757411200, 757414800, 757418400, 
757422000, 757425600, 757429200, 757432800, 757436400, 757440000, 
757443600, 757447200, 757454400, 757461600, 757465200, 757468800, 
757472400, 757476000, 757479600, 757483200, 757486800, 757490400, 
757494000, 757497600, 757501200, 757504800, 757508400, 757512000, 
757515600, 757519200, 757522800, 757526400, 757530000, 757533600, 
757537200, 757540800, 757544400, 757555200, 757558800, 757562400, 
757566000, 757569600, 757573200, 757576800, 757580400, 757584000, 
757587600, 757591200, 757594800, 757598400, 757602000, 757605600, 
757609200, 757612800, 757616400, 757620000, 757623600, 757641600, 
757645200, 757648800, 757652400, 757656000, 757659600, 757663200, 
757666800, 757670400, 757674000, 757677600, 757684800, 757688400, 
757692000, 757695600, 757699200, 757702800, 757706400, 757710000, 
757713600, 757717200, 757720800, 757724400, 757728000, 757731600, 
757735200, 757738800, 757742400, 757746000, 757749600, 757753200, 
757756800, 757760400, 757764000, 757767600, 757771200, 757774800, 
757778400, 757782000, 757785600, 757789200, 757792800, 757803600, 
757807200, 757814400, 757818000, 757821600, 757825200, 757828800, 
757832400, 757836000, 757839600, 757843200, 757846800, 757850400, 
757854000, 757857600, 757861200, 757864800, 757868400, 757872000, 
757875600, 757879200, 757882800, 757890000, 757900800, 757904400, 
757908000, 757911600, 757915200, 757918800, 757922400, 757926000, 
757929600, 757933200, 757936800, 757940400, 757944000, 757947600, 
757951200, 757954800, 757958400, 757962000, 757965600, 757969200, 
757976400, 757980000, 757983600, 757987200, 757990800, 757994400, 
757998000, 758001600, 758005200, 758008800, 758012400, 758016000, 
758019600, 758023200, 758026800, 758030400, 758034000, 758037600, 
758041200, 758044800, 758048400, 758052000, 758062800, 758066400, 
758070000, 758077200, 758080800, 758084400, 758088000, 758091600, 
758095200, 758098800, 758102400, 758106000, 758109600, 758113200, 
758116800, 758120400, 758124000, 758127600, 758131200, 758134800, 
758138400, 758145600, 758149200, 758152800, 758160000, 758163600, 
758167200, 758170800, 758174400, 758178000, 758181600, 758185200, 
758188800, 758192400, 758196000, 758199600, 758203200, 758206800, 
758210400, 758214000, 758217600, 758221200, 758224800, 758228400, 
758235600, 758246400, 758250000, 758253600, 758257200, 758260800, 
758264400, 758268000, 758271600, 758275200, 758278800, 758282400, 
758286000, 758289600, 758293200, 758296800, 758300400, 758304000, 
758307600, 758311200, 758314800, 758325600, 758329200, 758336400, 
758340000, 758343600, 758347200, 758350800, 758354400, 758358000, 
758361600, 758365200, 758368800, 758372400, 758376000, 758379600, 
758383200, 758386800, 758390400, 758394000, 758397600, 758401200, 
758404800, 758408400, 758419200, 758422800, 758426400, 758430000, 
758433600, 758437200, 758440800, 758444400, 758448000, 758451600, 
758455200, 758458800, 758462400, 758466000, 758469600, 758473200, 
758476800, 758480400, 758484000, 758487600, 758491200, 758494800, 
758502000, 758505600, 758509200, 758512800, 758516400, 758520000, 
758523600, 758527200, 758530800, 758534400, 758538000, 758541600, 
758545200, 758548800, 758552400, 758556000, 758559600, 758563200, 
758566800, 758570400, 758574000), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), lat = c(34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 34.2700004577637, 
34.2700004577637), lon = c(-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, -120.449996948242, 
-120.449996948242, -120.449996948242), wind_spd = c(10.3000001907349, 
9.89999961853027, 9.60000038146973, 8.30000019073486, 9.5, 10, 
8.39999961853027, 8.69999980926514, 9.89999961853027, 10.1999998092651, 
10.6999998092651, 9.39999961853027, 10.3999996185303, 11.5, 11.8000001907349, 
11.3000001907349, 10.8000001907349, 10, 10.6000003814697, 11.8999996185303, 
11.1000003814697, 11.6000003814697, 9.39999961853027, 9.60000038146973, 
11.1000003814697, 11.3999996185303, 11, 9.30000019073486, 10.1000003814697, 
8.10000038146973, 3, 2.70000004768372, 2.09999990463257, 0.100000001490116, 
0.600000023841858, 1.39999997615814, 0.800000011920929, 1.20000004768372, 
1.60000002384186, 4.59999990463257, 3.59999990463257, 4.80000019073486, 
6.80000019073486, 6.59999990463257, 6.19999980926514, 6.5, 7, 
5.69999980926514, 5.90000009536743, 5.09999990463257, 3.59999990463257, 
3.79999995231628, 5.80000019073486, 5.30000019073486, 6.09999990463257, 
6.69999980926514, 4.69999980926514, 4.59999990463257, 3.40000009536743, 
2.20000004768372, 1.29999995231628, 1.89999997615814, 5.59999990463257, 
7.59999990463257, 7.80000019073486, 7.19999980926514, 7.90000009536743, 
8.5, 8, 8, 5.90000009536743, 6.09999990463257, 8.19999980926514, 
9.30000019073486, 9.10000038146973, 7.19999980926514, 9.69999980926514, 
10.3000001907349, 9.5, 8.30000019073486, 10.1999998092651, 9.10000038146973, 
9.5, 11.1999998092651, 10.8000001907349, 11.1999998092651, 10.8999996185303, 
11.8999996185303, 12.3000001907349, 12.1999998092651, 12.1000003814697, 
12.8000001907349, 13.3999996185303, 12.6999998092651, 14.8000001907349, 
11.1000003814697, 13.1000003814697, 13.8999996185303, 12, 14, 
13.8999996185303, 11.3999996185303, 13.1000003814697, 12.8000001907349, 
13.8999996185303, 16.6000003814697, 18.1000003814697, 16.8999996185303, 
15.3000001907349, 14.6000003814697, 12.8000001907349, 14.3000001907349, 
14.3999996185303, 16.6000003814697, 12.3999996185303, 13.6000003814697, 
14.1000003814697, 16.7000007629395, 16.5, 17, 13.1999998092651, 
10.6999998092651, 15.6000003814697, 10, 10, 8.10000038146973, 
7.09999990463257, 6, 4.69999980926514, 4.90000009536743, 3.29999995231628, 
3.09999990463257, 0.899999976158142, 0.100000001490116, 0.600000023841858, 
1.5, 2.09999990463257, 3.40000009536743, 4.30000019073486, 4.80000019073486, 
5.90000009536743, 4.5, 4, 4.59999990463257, 3.70000004768372, 
3.20000004768372, 5.09999990463257, 4.40000009536743, 3.20000004768372, 
1.29999995231628, 0.699999988079071, 0.600000023841858, 1.10000002384186, 
2.40000009536743, 3.70000004768372, 1.60000002384186, 2.09999990463257, 
2.29999995231628, 1.89999997615814, 2.09999990463257, 3.29999995231628, 
3.79999995231628, 4.09999990463257, 4.5, 5.90000009536743, 6, 
7.80000019073486, 6.5, 8.30000019073486, 9.39999961853027, 11, 
11.6999998092651, 12.3999996185303, 12.1999998092651, 11.8999996185303, 
12.1999998092651, 13.8999996185303, 14.5, 13.3999996185303, 12.1999998092651, 
14, 11.8999996185303, 10.5, 11, 11.1000003814697, 12.8000001907349, 
11.3000001907349, 9.69999980926514, 11.3999996185303, 11, 12.3999996185303, 
12.5, 13.6999998092651, 14.6000003814697, 14.1999998092651, 12.3000001907349, 
13.3000001907349, 11.6000003814697, 11.8999996185303, 11.8000001907349, 
9.69999980926514, 11.8000001907349, 12, 8.80000019073486, 6.69999980926514, 
8.60000038146973, 3.09999990463257, 1.70000004768372, 0.400000005960464, 
0.800000011920929, 1.79999995231628, 3.09999990463257, 2.29999995231628, 
4, 3.09999990463257, 3.79999995231628, 5, 5.69999980926514, 4.19999980926514, 
5.30000019073486, 6.30000019073486, 6.59999990463257, 6.09999990463257, 
4.69999980926514, 4.80000019073486, 5, 3, 4.40000009536743, 5, 
8.10000038146973, 7.09999990463257, 7.80000019073486, 6.09999990463257, 
8.30000019073486, 11.1000003814697, 10.8000001907349, 10.5, 11.8999996185303, 
8.30000019073486, 3.90000009536743, 4.40000009536743, 4.5, 3.09999990463257, 
1.20000004768372, 3.40000009536743, 4.09999990463257, 4.59999990463257, 
4.69999980926514, 3.20000004768372, 1.89999997615814, 1.10000002384186, 
3.40000009536743, 3.90000009536743, 1.70000004768372, 0.200000002980232, 
2.59999990463257, 3.5, 5.09999990463257, 4.69999980926514, 5.19999980926514, 
7.19999980926514, 8.19999980926514, 5.40000009536743, 2.09999990463257, 
2.90000009536743, 1.10000002384186, 1.5, 1.29999995231628, 2.40000009536743, 
1.29999995231628, 1.5, 1.39999997615814, 3.40000009536743, 3.20000004768372, 
3.20000004768372, 3.59999990463257, 0.600000023841858, 0, 2.09999990463257, 
3.29999995231628, 3.79999995231628, 2.79999995231628, 4.69999980926514, 
6, 5.30000019073486, 6.40000009536743, 6, 5.90000009536743, 4.90000009536743, 
3.20000004768372, 2.90000009536743, 2.90000009536743, 1.60000002384186, 
1.29999995231628, 2.70000004768372, 2.90000009536743, 2.79999995231628, 
3.79999995231628, 3.29999995231628, 3.20000004768372)), row.names = c(NA, 
-300L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: In the example showed you showed only a single date `1994-01-01`.  Perhaps `library(dplyr);data %>% mutate(date = as.Date(time)) %>% mutate(Flag = c(0, diff(date)) > 1)`.  If it is to check for the whole data `data %>% mutate(date = as.Date(time)) %>% mutate(Flag = c(0, diff(date)) <= 1) %>% pull(Flag) %>% all(.)`

Comment: updated sample data for more then just one day

Comment: Can you show your expected output for that data.  It is all consecutive i.e. 1994-01-01 and 1994-01-02

Comment: I want to check if the data is consecutive, 1994-01-01, 1994-01-02, 1994-01-03, etc. You second line of code indicates my data is not consecutive which was my concern due to attempting to calculate rolling averages

Comment: It indicates the column is all consecutive `data %>% mutate(date = as.Date(time)) %>% mutate(Flag = c(0, diff(date)) <= 1) %>% pull(Flag) %>% all(.)#
[1] TRUE`

Comment: Are you trying to create a group of consecutive dates and apply rolling mean on the data within the group? `library(zoo);`  I am creating a  'value' column (incase you have different column, change the name. `dat %>% mutate(value = rnorm(n())) %>% group_by(grp = cumsum(c(0, diff(as.Date(Time)) > 1))) %>% mutate(rollMean = rollmean(value, k = 3, fill = NA, align = "left")) %>% ungroup`

Comment: @akrun yes, that is what i am trying to do. I want to have rolling mean calculations but not have issues if there are large gaps in the date range

Comment: @akrun I have updated the question and data with a dput of the data. It would be great to have a way to calculate 4 day, 7 day, and 14 day rolling averages but some how account for the missing days in the date columns